# In Taylor's formula, there is a remainder term that includes an unknown value z at which the (n+1)st derivative is taken; what is the range for it?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

In the final exam of MIT OCW 18.01 there is the following problem:

> a) Find the Taylor Series of $\ln(1+x)$ centered at $a=0$.

> c) Use the first two non-zero terms of the power series found in a) to
> approximate $\ln(3/2)$

> d) Give an upper bound on the error in your approximation in (c) using Taylor's inequality.

**My question is about d), finding the upper bound on the error. I will show my reasoning first, and then the solution I saw which I can't understand**

The Taylor Series isn't difficult to find, it is
$$
x - \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} + \ldots = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}.
$$

The approximation for $\ln(3/2)$ is
$$
\ln(3.2) = ln(1+0.5) \approx 0.5 - \frac{0.5^2}{2} = \frac{3}{8}.
$$

Regarding the error for this approximation, here is my line of reasoning:

We can use Taylor's formula expressing our function as a sum of a polynomial approximation term and a remainder $$f(x) = P_2(x) + R_2(x)$$

$$P_2(x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2}$$

$$R_2(x) = \frac{f^{3}(z)}{3!}x^3$$

with $z$ a number between $0$ and $x$.

$$f^{3}(z)=\frac{(-1)^2 2!}{(1+z)^3} = \frac{2!}{(1+z)^3}$$

So

$$R_2(x) = \frac{x^3}{3(1+z)^3}$$

In the case of $x=0.5$

$$R_2(0.5) = \frac{1}{24(1+z)^3}$$

We don't know exactly what $z$ is, but since it is between $0$ and $1/2$, and $R_2(0.5)$ is decreasing in $z$, we can check the value at $z=1/2$ to find an upper bound.

For $z=0.5$ we get $$R_2(0.5) < \frac{1}{81}$$

The official solution for finding the upper bound of the error is as follows:

$$|R_n(x)| \leq M_n \frac{|x^{n+1}|}{(n+1)!}$$

where $x=0.5$ and $n=2$

In addition, $$M_n \geq |f^{(n+1)}(x)| \implies M_2 \geq \frac{2}{(1+x)^3}$$

for all $|x| \leq 0.5$. The maximum of $M_2$ in this range is for $x=-0.5$, which gives M_2 = 16, so $$|R_n(0.5)| \leq 16\frac{(0.5)^3}{3!}=\frac{1}{3}$$

**Okay, so the length of the above was just to have all the steps in case someone needs to see them. Thing is the calculations are in agreement, but instead of restricting the $z$ value in the remainder term to between 0 and 1/2, they allow $z \leq 0.5$, so negative values are allowed**. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything: your version seems to be the standard one, while theirs is correct but suboptimal.

Comment: But this is not right: "since it is between $0$ and $1/2$, and $R_2(0.5)$ is decreasing in $z$, we can check the value at $z=1/2$ to find an upper bound." Since $R_2(0.5)$ is decreasing in $z$, you should choose the least value of $z$ to get an upper bound.

Comment: Note that $\ln(3/2) - \frac38 \approx 0.030465$ whereas $1/81 \approx 0.012346.$ So the error is actually much bigger than you estimated. If you had come up with $1/24$, which is approximately $0.041667,$ that would have been much better.